# How to style GtkNotebook stepper arrows?

Tags: gtk, themes, gtknotebook

I'm trying to style a [GtkNotebook](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.8/GtkNotebook.html) using a [GtkCssProvider](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.8/GtkCssProvider.html). I can control most things using a `GtkNotebook` or `GtkNotebook tab` selector, but I can't figure out how to style the scroll arrows on the side:

[image: GtkNotebook screenshot]

If I apply a style that changes every element, e.g.:

```
* {
    color: #f00;
}
```

it changes the arrows (and everything else), so it appears they do support theming:

[image: Notebook with red style]

What is the actual selector that matches those arrows, so I can apply a style to just them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtknotebook.c?id=3.12.2#n5558), arrows in `GtkNotebook` are not full fledged widgets; they are just rendered with [`gtk_render_arrow()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtk-render-arrow).

The [code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkstylecontext.c#n3662) of `gtk_render_arrow` shows the CSS class [`arrow`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#GTK-STYLE-CLASS-ARROW:CAPS) is applied before the rendering. This means you can customize the position within the `notebook` class and the rendering in the `arrow` subclass, e.g.:

```
.notebook {
    -GtkNotebook-initial-gap: 20;
    -GtkNotebook-arrow-spacing: 20;
}
.notebook.arrow {
    color: black;
}
.notebook.arrow:prelight {
    color: white
}
.notebook.arrow:insensitive {
    color: gray
}
```

Different theme engines can provide additional customizations.